# PDO rowCount() or exec()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It seems to me that both [`rowCount()`](http://php.chinaunix.net/manual/zh/function.PDOStatement-rowCount.php) and `exec()` *Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement*  .

Why keep the duplicate stuff there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not duplicate they have different-2 roles to play at different situations.

> exec() => Execute the sql and returns
>   affected rows.
>
> rowCount() => Does not executed any
>   statement but returns rows affected by
>   last sql.

They are different in this way

If you are using execute() then rowCount come into it's role

```
$del = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM fruit');
$del->execute();
$count = $del->rowCount();
```

And when you are using exec no need to `rowCount()`

```
$count = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM fruit WHERE colour = 'red'");
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
```